# Blender viewport frozen(can't perform operations)

Tags: 3d-view

I was working and probably hit some shortcut and it froze my viewport, i can not select anything other than what is selected nor i can delete stuff. What could that be ? here is a quick gif [image: Text]

Comment: Even the gif is not working! Maybe your computer has a ghost.

Comment: it did in chrome , probably cache lol, reuploaded it

Answer (score 0):

Concerning my question : shortcut hid collection , but it was visible in local view